# Show that $f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{z}{e^z-1} & z ≠ 0 \\ 1 & z=0 \end{cases}$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $U$ be the open set of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that for all non-zero $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $z ≠ 2ik\pi$. Let $$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{z}{e^z-1} & z ≠ 0 \\ 1 & z=0 \end{cases}.$$ Show that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$.

How should I go about showing that f is holomorphic close to $0$? The hint that I was given was to express $e^z-1 = zg(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic and non-zero at $0$, but I don't understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand: the existence of such a $g$, or why it is useful?

Comment: @AnneBauval both, if such a $g$ exists then doesn't it follow that $g(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$? And then $g$ is undefined at $z=0$. I guess we could define $g$ as $\frac{1}{f}$ but I don't see how that helps us.

Comment: *If* such a $g$ exists *then* $f=\frac1g$ is "holomorphic close to $0$", since $g$ is "non-zero at $0$". Now, *why* *g* exists: play with the power series of $\exp.$

Comment: $$e^z -1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}-1 =z \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}}_{g(z)}$$

Answer (score 3):

For nonzero $z\in U$ you have that $f$ is holomorphic simply because sum, products, and quotients of holomorphic are holomorphic if defined.

At $z=0$, we calculate $f'(0)$:
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}z=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\frac z{e^z-1}-1}z
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z-e^z+1}{z(e^z-1)}
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\frac12\,z^2+o(z^3)}{z^2+o(z^3))}=\frac12.
$$
Hence $f'(0)$ exists and $f$ is holomorphic at $0$.